# Is there a way to know the right time scale for Unity ML Agent Training?

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, timedelta, ml-agent

I am training an AI to learn how to play flappy bird.

I trained it with a high time scale and it performs well only in that specific pace. When it's applied to the default time scale 1 of the game, it's pretty bad. So now I want to train it at the exact time scale that the game is in. Problem is, time scale 1 in game is visibly and considerably slower than time scale 1 of training. I am using Time.deltaTime throughout my code.

How can I know exactly what time scale to set the training to?

Comment: I think the time scale shouldn't change the model's performance. Is the model being trained on any time-dependent parameter?

Answer (score 2):

it's a pretty non-technical fix but maybe just lower the time-scale of the training until it looks as close to the time scale in your game as possible. another thing to keep in mind is that when time.deltatime is used in the fixedupdate() function, it actually gets time.fixeddeltatime, not time.deltatime (reference to the info here `https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html`).